# Facebook Graph API (Tell people about my app)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible using the Graph API to tell the my friends about the an app? 
I looked through the documentation and I can't find any, maybe I missed it. I can see I can post onmy wall, but nothing regarding sharing a link/app. Thanks

Comment: How is posting on your wall not sharing?

Comment: yes its possible and spamming your friends is a good way to get your app booted for spam by facebook

Answer (score 1):

Sharing a link is a part of the Graph API.  You can add a lot of variables to a Post request.  See the official documentation here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

As an example, I used the message, link, name, caption, description, and icon properties with the graph API to create this dialog (using the Facebook iOS SDK).

[image: Sample Post Dialog on iOS Using Facebook SDK]

Comment: Feel free to mark this as the answer if it answered your problem.

Comment: How do you present this UI using the graph API?